# Nodejs: stream request payload to java application, then to response

Tags: java, node.js, stream, pipe, wkhtmltopdf

I need to convert html to pdf via streams, because saving the html to a file and then reading it again to send to wkhtmltopdf eats up all available memory.

Here's how I think it can be accomplished, using wkhtmltopdf:

```
Node stream > java application wrapping wkhtmltopdf > Node stream
```

So, in my application, I would read from the datasource, pipe the data to the java application which converts the data to pdf and then pipe to the response stream.

Currently, I'm doing some simple tests to see how it works. My problem is piping the data from node to the java application and getting it back to pipe it to the response stream.

Both codes are simple enough:

Node (yes, that's coffeescript):

```
http = require 'http'
child = require('child_process').spawn 'java', ['PdfStream'], stdout: ['pipe', 'pipe', process.stderr]

server = http.createServer().listen 8000
server.on 'request', (req, res) ->
    res.writeHead 200, 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
    req.pipe(child.stdout, end: false).pipe res, end: true
```

Java:

```
public class PdfStream {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String[] command = {"wkhtmltopdf", "-", "-"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = builder.start();

    BufferedWriter pdfOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            pdfOut.write(line);
            pdfOut.flush();
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //  exception? what exception?
    } finally {
        if (pdfOut != null) {
            pdfOut.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I fire a POST request to the node server, nothing comes out of it. I have tried to write to Sytem.out, and if I

```
cat file.html | java PdfStream
```

, it works. Also, if I change the outputstream passed to the ProcessBuilder, as in

```
String[] command = {"wkhtmltopdf", "-", "test.pdf"};
```

everything works fine, too.

Can you tell what's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, it hit me: what's the point of using a java wrapper to execute a program? I can do it directly from node. Then, I read the wkhtmltopdf documentation and, while looking for the right way to pass streams into it, I stumbled upon a good soul's npm package called wkhtmltox (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltox) which does extacly that. The way to do what I was trying couldn't be simpler:

```
server = http.createServer().listen 8000
server.on 'request', (req, res) ->
    res.writeHead 200, 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
    converter.pdf(req).pipe(res).on('finish', -> console.log 'finished')
```

And it works as promised.